# is there any lib for website connect to printer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, receipt

I am using ruby 2.3.3 and rails 5. Can you instruct me the way to print receipt in printer. I had an idea that I just build a pdf-page then use function "print" of browser. But if you have any great solution for this problem, please share with me.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I see this as a JavaScript solution rather than a Rails one. Like you have said, you have to generate an PDF, and then you can do something like this.

```
<%= link_to 'Print_the_PDF', '#', :onclick => 'window.print();return false;'%>
```

Comment: Does it print the button also doesn't it? When I tested "window.print" on w3c I saw it print all page including button. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_print. And in receipt client don't want to see that button obviously